# run gazebo remotely

Tags: ros, gazebo, tabletop, ssh, remote

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am experimenting with the pick and place demo: http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/SimpleGraspingDemo
I can run it on two machines : a dual-core and a 16-core machines.
However if I try to connect to the 16-core via SSH and run it the Gazebo dies.
I can see the gazebo window for a couple of seconds and then it fails.

I am connecting via "ssh -X" and "ssh -Y" neither works. Also, I do not have direct root access to the 16-core but know s.o. who has.

Edit: They told me that I can run gazebo headless, but that is not going to be enough.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9324/run-gazebo-remotely/) by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 535 on 2011-03-07

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, to run gazebo on a remote machine, you'll need X running on your remote machine and export DISPLAY variable to point to the local display on the remote machine before launching gazebo.  For example, if your local machine (dual-core) is called machine1 and remote machine (16-core) is called machine2.  Suppose a ros core has been started on machine2.  To start gazebo on machine2, you can:

1. ssh into the remote machine.

> ssh machine2

2. set up your ROS_MASTER_URI to point to the ros core

> export ROS_MASTER_URI="http://machine2:11311"

3. make sure X is up and running on machine2 and xhost allows your user to access the display, then

> export DISPLAY=:0

4. and start gazebo as usual, e.g.

> roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch

5. Back on machine1, make sure to point your ROS_MASTER_URI to machine2 and you should be able to see all the simulated PR2 ros topics.
   .

Note that the gazebo gui, if enabled, will be spawned on the remote machine2. So it is recommended that -g flag is given to turn off the gazebo gui if you're going to be working from the local machine, e.g.

> < node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo" args="-g -u $(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/empty.world" respawn="false" output="screen" />

I am looking for ways to make this process more transparent, please let me know if you run into any issues.
Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitar Simeonov](https://answers.ros.org/users/256/dimitar-simeonov/) on 2011-03-18**:
that was very helpful but I'd like to be able to see the GUI on machine 1.  I see the GUI chrome loading on machine1  but then I get /opt/ros/cturtle/stacks/simulator_gazebo/gazebo/build/gazebo/server/rendering/OgreCreator.cc:441 : Exception: Unable to create the rendering window

**Comment by [mbforbes](https://answers.ros.org/users/15401/mbforbes/) on 2014-07-16**:
I know this is old, but I'd also really like to do this and it's not quite working! I exported DISPLAY=:0 and added the -g argument to the Gazebo node; still seg faults. Running Gazebo 1.5 (pr2_gazebo on Groovy). Is there a way to verify step 3 (X up and running)? `service lightdm status` says OK.

**Comment by [aditi741997](https://answers.ros.org/users/41386/aditi741997/) on 2019-08-26**:
Can you plz elaborate on the step 3? I have also tried setting up the display and -g, and still get seg faults. I am not sure if I set up X correctly